Tomcat 9 With Java8 on almalinux error opening war
I am setting up a playtest environment with multiple tomcat and multiple openlogic jdk versions.
It seems that when I put a war file in /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.97/webapps and restart the server I get this log in the catalina out.
    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.97/webapps/name-of.war
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:602)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:571)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:603)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1014)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1866)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:816)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1584)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:312)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:389)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:336)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:776)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:721)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:211)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:874)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:735)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error starting the loader
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:380)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4314)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:599)
                ... 37 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
                at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.createClassLoader(WebappLoader.java:483)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:357)
                ... 41 more

I looked around a bit and it seems that the openjdk version that I should use is
openlogic-openjdk-8u432-b06-linux-x64
can someone help me decipher this error?

Your war is missing a class: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader

OH thank you I will look into it and let you know.
